# How can I open two urls in two tabs in a single click?

Tags: php, html, url, tabs

I have 2 urls
http://www.example.com
and
http://www.nana.com

If I click the below link the above 2 urls should open in two tabs..
a href="#">Click /a

May anyone help me to acheive this one?

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
<a id="test" href="#"> CLick </a>
<script type="text/javascript">

  document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){
   window.open("http://www.google.com",'_blank');
   window.open("http://www.p3php.in",'_blank');
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Pratik..Thank you for your answer..It is worked for me..Thanks again for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="window.open('http://www.nana.com')">Click</a>
```

Comment: This opens only the link in the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com');
    window.open('http://yahoo.com');" >Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do it

HTML:

```
<a id="link">Click me!!</a>
```

JS:

```
var link = document.getElementById("link");

link.onclick = function() {
    window.open("http://yahoo.com");
    window.open("http://google.com");
};
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

hope this works

```
<html>
<script>
function pageloader()
{

 window.open("http://www.example.com", '_blank');
 window.open("http://www.google.com", '_blank');

}

</script>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="pageloader();">Click here </a>


</body>
</html>
```

goodluck!