# Is that possible to open 2 web page in 1 link

Tags: html

Is that possible to open 2 web page when user browse domain example.com

I would like to set it on homepage.
When user browse domain example.com, it will go to example.com (link1) and example.com/articlename (link2)

How to do that? The link2 above must set open in new tab.

Comment: There are a lot of this kind of question. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064998/how-to-make-a-link-open-multiple-pages-when-clicked), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566970/how-can-i-open-two-pages-from-a-single-click-without-using-javascript), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372865/how-can-i-open-two-urls-in-two-tabs-in-a-single-click)

Comment: @vee hi, if you key in the domain example.com in browser. These <a href> is unable solve my problem. <a href> must put it in a text. Mine is domain redirect to 2 web page.

Comment: It is already answered in those questions. They are work with link (`<a href>`) or work when just open the page (`window.open()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="link1" onclick="window.open('link2');
return true;">Click Link</a>
```

When user Click Link, it will go to (link1) and specific page (link2) open in new tab.

Comment: can set it as meta? I am not using this in a link. example if user go example.com, it will redirect to example.com and example.com/artilce/01

Comment: meta no this function.  just refresh <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=link">